# How to retry 'Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response' error

Tags: http, exception, python-requests, connection, urllib3

```
def some_func(url):
    try:
        requests.get(url)
    except exception as e:
        # retry code here
```

I want to retry the request if the previous request gets a connection aborted error. How can I implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [requests docs](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/api/#requests.adapters.HTTPAdapter):

```py
s = requests.Session()
a = requests.adapters.HTTPAdapter(max_retries=3)
s.mount('http://', a)
s.mount('https://', a)

def some_func(url):
    s.get(url)
```

For finer retry behaviour see [urrlib3's doc](https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/urllib3.util.html#module-urllib3.util.retry) on `Retry`.